# Select last row and sum of column in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

My table:

```
date        Id  name    amount  payment
01/05/2017  01  Maxi    50000   Dec’16
01/10/2017  02  Shirly  50000   Jan’17
01/28/2017  01  Maxi    100000  Jan’17
02/12/2017  02  Shirly  50000   Feb’17
```

What query do I need to get this in MySQL?

```
Id  name    SUM(amount)  LAST(payment)
01  Maxi    1,50,000      Jan’17
02  Shirly  100,000       Feb’17
```

Comment: You should've stored the payment column as yyyymm. Ordering or finding max or min on the current format is just too much pain

Comment: What is the data type of the `payment` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` to accumulate the *payment* values in a certain order, and then use `substring_index` to extract the first from that:

```
select   id, 
         name, 
         sum(amount), 
         substring_index(group_concat(payment order by date desc), ',', 1)
from     mytable
group by id
```

This assumes you want to take the last payment in the order by the *date* column. The *payment* column seems to be a non-date value, which will be useless to sort by.

If you need to take the last value of *payment* in the order of payment date, you should define that column as a date. Then you can do a simple `max`:

```
select   id, 
         name, 
         sum(amount), 
         max(payment)
from     mytable
group by id
```

Comment: What is `date ` in this question?

Comment: It is mentioned in the table data. I have added a paragraph to my answer.

Comment: Why he required to declare that column as `DATE`,even though there is `STR_TO_DATE()`  function there in mysql. And here you had assume something.
We know you are super senior but this not justify your answer.

Comment: It is bad practice to rely on str_to_date as you cannot benefit from indexes and have no input validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id,name,SUM(amount),MAX(STR_TO_DATE(payment,'%b’%y')) AS LAST(payment) FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY Id
```

Try above code. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @GurV yes it's also quite good.Please check my updated answer.